# How to put out the outline on chips when it's selected?

Tags: flutter

I'm using Chips for radio button that designed like the attached image.
And when I selected one, want to put out the outline and change the background color.

Is it possible to do with chips?

[image]

```
ChoiceChip(
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
              label: Text(item),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
              selected: sortPlaceChecked == item,
              onSelected: (selected) {
                setState(() {
                  sortPlaceChecked = item;
                  _inputPlace = false;
                });
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the sortPlaceChecked == item condition to apply some style or not; for example is you want a red background for selected chips you can do as follow, use the same principle for the border.

```
ChoiceChip(
    ...
    backgroundColor: sortPlaceChecked == item ? Colors.red : Colors.transparent,
)
```